# Project 2003 and .NET COM Primary Interop Assemblies

Tags: c#, com, primary-interop-assembly

I am creating an app in C# using the .NET COM Primary Interop Assemblies. I was wondering if this will be able to open and read files from both Project 2003 and Project 2007. Also, does Project have to be installe don the computer that is running this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Yes and Yes.  You'll have to use the 2003 PIA, Office versions beyond this are backwards compatible with older COM interface specifications.  But of course you won't be able to use 2007 specific features.  You can't do anything with Project if it isn't installed on the machine.  Project 2003 isn't likely to be able to read Project 2007 files unless the file was saved in 2003 format.  No problem the other way around.

Comment: Thanks. Having to have Project installed may be an issue. Might have to use the XML instead, though I would prefer to do it this way.